# New Asus TUF B650Plus motherboard with VGA QLED on: any solutions other than return it?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, asus

I've been building a gaming PC for my niece. The specs are the following:

- AMD Ryzen 5 7600X
- Asus TUF GAMING B650-PLUS (the non-Wifi one)
- 16 Gb. 6000 Mhz RAM
- 1 WD Blue 1 Tb. NVMe SSD
- Nvidia 4060 GPU wth 8Gb RAM.
- Tempest PSU PRO 750W 80+ Bronze Power Supply Phanteks G360A case

When I first turned it on, the fans (and internal LED lights) turned on, but the screen didn't display anything, so I tried removing the GPU and plugging the HDMI cable directly into the motherboard. No dice either. So I googled and tried using the BIOS flashback to flash the RAM (following https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1038568). It didn't work either.

Eventually, I realised that the motherboard's QLED VGA light was on, even without any GPU installed (it was hard to see, since the case has lots of lights and the QLEDs are tiny). So I returned the CPU and exchanged it for another one. Today I installed it again... and again the VGA light is on.

The obvious solution here would be to exchange the motherboard too, but I'm wondering if there's any other way to try to solve this. Some quick googling shows lots of people with QLED VGA lights on that have nevertheless managed to solve it (though many of them use different models, have setups that have worked in the past...).

So... what else could it be?

Comment: “So... what else could it be?” - Nothing, it’s likely the CPU socket.